# How to calculate hour difference from a text string "7.00 pm to 8.00 pm" or "11.00 am to 12.00 pm" using excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to calculate number of hours and minutes from a text string given, Currently I have created below formula using some excel built-in functions,

Sample Text String:

> 7.00pm to 8.00pm or 9.00am to 11.45pm or 1.20pm to 3.40pm

Formula created-

```
=CONCATENATE(REPLACE(SUM(NUMBERVALUE(REPLACE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-11),5,2,""))-NUMBERVALUE(REPLACE(A1,5,100,""))),2,3," Hour")," ",CONCATENATE(RIGHT(SUM(NUMBERVALUE(REPLACE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-11),5,2,""))-NUMBERVALUE(REPLACE(A1,5,100,""))),1)*10, " Minutes"))
```

The above formula gets the number value from the given string and than calculate the difference, after that it separate the value and than concatenate with given text

This works on string like

> 7.00pm to 9.40pm

Output:

> 2 Hour 40 Minutes

But I think the approach what I have taken is not the best way and also it will not work when time is am to pm means "9.00am to 1.00pm", So is there any other way through which difference in hours can be calculated.
Or can we fine tune this formula...

Please let me know if any further info is needed on this query

Comment: Does your system time really use a `.` instead of a `:` ?

Comment: its not the system time, actually a excel sheet is filled manually by different person daily, and while entering details they use `.` for differentiating hours and min

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time belongs as time. The following formula undoes all the mistakes made during input and computes a true time value.

```
=TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, ".", ":"), "am", " am"), "pm", " pm"), 8))-TIMEVALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, ".", ":"), "am", " am"), "pm", " pm"), 8))
```

Give the cell a custom number format of,

```
h \hou\r\s \a\n\d m \mi\nut\e\s_)
```

The format does not change the fact that you have a raw underlying value which can be used in future calculations.

[image]

Comment: Thanks your approach is very cool, I wasn't knowing about `SUBSTITUTE` and `TIMEVALUE`