# Extract the hour from the h" hour(s) and "m" minute(s)" in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have the list of data that showing the Hours and the Minutes that I extract from the system. I need to be extract the hours.
As example below, column B first row, the Hours would be 64 and the minutes would be 46.

But when I used the formula =Hour , its turn up the different value since its actually decimal number.
[image]

Cannot use left() , it will give the actual decimal number.

[image]

Updated:

We tried the @harun24HR 's but cannot readable the value.
But if you noticed, if i copy and paste the value is different. thats why the search not applicable.
[image]

4th Update:
To Solar Mike, I have tried the formula given from the thread the i think the value not readable
[image]

Comment: Use left() and mid() with find().

Comment: Just tried, cannot it will give the actual number which is the decimal number.

can see my updated image

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/52126465/4961700

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract two numbers from string using formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60506653/extract-two-numbers-from-string-using-formula)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/70929562/4961700

Comment: On some of your attempts, try formatting column K as date.

Comment: What would be the expected output? Also, you talk about column B but none of your screenshots show column B...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time value is already a number in time format so you just need it to change it to decimal system. Dates and time values are numbers. Even if you see it as `30/09/2019` or `12:00:00`, actually, for Excel, both cases are numbers.

First date Excel can recognize properly is 01/01/1900 which integer numeric value is 1. Number 2 would be 02/01/1900 and so on. Actually, today is 44659.

Now, about your data, you posted this screenshoot:

[image]

So the value is numeric, not text/string. In Excel, what you see is not always what you have. Probably that column has been formatted using custom mask. My fake data is like this:

[image]

The numeric value is `02/01/1900  16:46:36` (or `02/01/1900  4:46:36 PM` it depends on your regional settings) but I've applied a custom format like this:

`[hh]" hours" mm " minutes"`

So what I have is a number but what I see is a text!

We have to work with the number (to be honest, ist's easier to work with numbers), so to extract the total hours, minutes and seconds.

[image]

Formula in B1: `=INT(A1*24)` total hours

Formula in C1: `=INT(A1*24*60-B1*60)` total minutes

Formula in D1: `=A1*24*60*60-B1*60*60-C1*60` total seconds

This should guide you on whatever are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

It's a time value which Excel stores as calculated value based on 24 hours = `1`.

To retrieve the hours only you can use:
`=INT(A2*24)`

To retrieve the minutes only you can use:
`=(A1-(INT(A1*24)/24))*24*60`

Answer (score 0):

From your current sample data you try-

For hour `=LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2)-1)` 
For minutes `=RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2," minutes",""),2)`

[image]

Comment: @harun24HR Hi, you can see my updated image